# Simulator reverts to home screen if I delete a row in table view

Tags: ios, ios-4.2

I am using a table view displaying (say 16) rows of random data.  If I delete a row, the simulator reverts to the home screen.  If I touch to reload, I again have 16 rows of DIFFERENT random data. Same behavior if I scroll the screen.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what are you getting for an error report when the app crashes

Answer (score 1):

A revert to the home screen means your app has crashed.  Run the app from the XCode Debugger to help find out where.

A UITableView is the View of MVC, not the Model.  If you didn't store your random data in a Model object somewhere, the exact same data can't be redisplayed when the View refreshes and asks for data again.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this idea a try and let you know how it works out.